# Hide servlet name in the url

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-mapping

In a website I have some links in a navbar like this

```
<li><a href="?page=pagename">PAGE</a></li>
```

and I load the linked page with JAVA in JSP page, then I submit data through a form by GET, after this my URL become

```
www.sitename.com/Servlet
```

then I'm not able to load the page by

```
?page=pagename
```

because I have the Servlet name in the URL.

How I can hide or delete the servlet name?

Comment: it will be good if you can provide some more code to understand

Comment: @Arjit there's no relevant code to show here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`servlet-mapping`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1015060) in your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easier if all those JSPs are in a common path. E.g. /app/*.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.FriendlyURLServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

with

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo() + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This assumes the JSPs to be in /WEB-INF folder so that they cannot be requested directly. This will show `/WEB-INF/search.jsp` on http://example.com/app/search.